# Understanding the Stanford CoreNLP Coreference set notation

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using stanford corenlp. To understand more clrearly the coreference set I need help. for the sentence

"Kosgi Santosh sent an email to Stanford University. He didn't get a reply" i got the 
coreference set
(2,1,[1,2)) -> (1,2,[1,3)), that is: "He" -> "Kosgi Santosh“

So far I understand the meaning of "(2,1," is 2nd sentence 1st word and "(1,2," is 1st sentence 2nd word. But can not understand the meaning of [1,2) and [1,3).

Could you please explain.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I needed this bit of information for my research as well.

After some digging, I found out that what ones gets are, in order:

- sentence for the mention
- position of the mention's head word in the sentence (i.e. He and Santosh)
- an interval `[#first_word_for_mention, #end)` which follows the mathematical notation for sets, i.e. bracket `[` indicating the left-hand boundary must be included, and parenthesis `)` indicating to exclude the right-hand boundary. In other words, the first number is the start word the mention, the second number is the word right after the last one belonging to the mention (whether it exists or not).

source http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp_output2.html